# How to read the state of "switch case" outside in the next function?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure it out that how to to read the state of the switch case in the ReSults function as shown in the code... The `result` function should read the `switch` state from `calculation` function and process it.

Code:

```
void CalCulation()
{
    cout << "Choice: "; char UserChoice; cin>>UserChoice;
    double vAdd1, vAdd2;
    switch(UserChoice)
    {
    case '+':
        cout << " + :: Enter the first value: "; cin << vAdd1;
        cout << " + :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vAdd2;
        ReSults(vAdd1, Vadd2);
    }
}
void ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, char UserChoice)
{
    if(UserChoice == '+')
    {
        double reSultOutputAdd = vAdd1+vAdd2;
        cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputAdd << '\n';
    }
}
```

`Full version`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
//Calculator
void MainMenu();
void CalCulation();
void ReSults(double , double, char);
bool isValid(string err_msg)
{
    if(cin.rdstate())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>:: max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
        MainMenu();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    MainMenu();

    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n The program runs Correctly" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
void MainMenu()
{
    cout << "Main Menu" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter + for Calculation" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter - for Subtraction" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter * for Multiplication" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter / for Devision" << '\n';
    cout << "------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << "Chose any option for the list." << '\n';
    CalCulation();
}
void CalCulation()
{
    cout << "Choice: "; char UserChoice; cin>>UserChoice;
    double vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2;
    switch(UserChoice)
    {
    case '+':do{
        cout << " + :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vAdd1;
        cout << " + :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vAdd2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, UserChoice);break;
    case '-':do{
        cout << " - :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vSub1;
        cout << " - :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vSub2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vSub1, vSub2, UserChoice);break;
    case '*':do{
        cout << " * :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vMul1;
        cout << " * :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vMul2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vMul1, vMul2, UserChoice);break;
    case '/':do{
        cout << " / :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vDiv1;
        cout << " / :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vDiv2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vDiv1, vDiv2, UserChoice);break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong Choice or Not allowed, Try again!" << '\n';
    }
}
void ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, double vSub1, double vSub2, double vMul1, double vMul2, double vDiv1, double vDiv2, char UserChoice)
{
    if(UserChoice == '+')
    {
        double reSultOutputAdd = vAdd1+vAdd2;
            cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputAdd << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '-')
    {
        double reSultOutputSub = vSub1-vSub2;
            cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputSub << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '+')
    {
        double reSultOutputMul = vMul1*vMul2;
            cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputMul << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '+')
    {
        double reSultOutputDiv = vDiv1/vDiv2;
            cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputDiv << '\n';
    }

}
```

Comment: @BoBTFish yes but how pass? I tried and it's not working with the error |undefined reference to `ReSults(double, double, char)'

Comment: ```void ReSults(double,double,char)``` make sure you declared this on your function prototype

Comment: UserChoice = '+' --> Typo? Did you mean UserChoice == '+' ?

Comment: yes its =='+' and one more error : undefined reference to `ReSults(double, double, char)'|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <limits>
using namespace std;
//Calculator
void MainMenu();
void CalCulation();
void ReSults(double , double, double , double, double , double, double , double, char);
bool isValid(string err_msg)
{
    if(cin.rdstate())
    {
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>:: max(), '\n');
        system("cls");
        MainMenu();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
int main()
{
    MainMenu();

    cout << "\n\n\n\n\n\n The program runs Correctly" << '\n';
    return 0;
}
void MainMenu()
{
    cout << "Main Menu" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter + for Calculation" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter - for Subtraction" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter * for Multiplication" << '\n';
    cout << "Enter / for Devision" << '\n';
    cout << "------------------------------" << '\n';
    cout << "Chose any option for the list." << '\n';
    CalCulation();
}
void CalCulation()
{
    cout << "Choice: "; char UserChoice; cin>>UserChoice;
    double vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2;
    switch(UserChoice)
    {
    case '+':do{
        cout << " + :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vAdd1;
        cout << " + :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vAdd2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2, UserChoice);break;
    case '-':do{
        cout << " - :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vSub1;
        cout << " - :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vSub2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2, UserChoice);break;
    case '*':do{
        cout << " * :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vMul1;
        cout << " * :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vMul2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2, UserChoice);break;
    case '/':do{
        cout << " / :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vDiv1;
        cout << " / :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vDiv2;
    }while (!isValid("You have not entered any number, try again with a correct input data."));
    ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, vSub1, vSub2, vMul1, vMul2, vDiv1, vDiv2, UserChoice);break;
    default:
        cout << "Wrong Choice or Not allowed, Try again!" << '\n';
    }
}
void ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, double vSub1, double vSub2, double vMul1, double vMul2, double vDiv1, double vDiv2, char UserChoice){
    if(UserChoice == '+'){
        double reSultOutputAdd = vAdd1+vAdd2;
            cout << "The result for Addition: "<< reSultOutputAdd << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '-'){
        double reSultOutputSub = vSub1-vSub2;
            cout << "The result for Subtraction: "<< reSultOutputSub << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '+'){
        double reSultOutputMul = vMul1*vMul2;
            cout << "The result for Multiplication: "<< reSultOutputMul << '\n';
    }else if(UserChoice == '+'){
        double reSultOutputDiv = vDiv1/vDiv2;
            cout << "The result for Division: "<< reSultOutputDiv << '\n';
    } }
```

Comment: oh thank you, I missed those double I thought it need only doubles because at a time I send only 2 doubles.

Answer (score 3):

```
void CalCulation();
void ReSults(double, double, char);

void CalCulation()
{
    cout << "Choice: "; char UserChoice; cin >> UserChoice;
    double vAdd1, vAdd2;
    switch (UserChoice)
    {
    case '+':
        cout << " + :: Enter the first value: "; cin >> vAdd1;
        cout << " + :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vAdd2;
        ReSults(vAdd1, vAdd2, UserChoice);
    }
}

void ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, char UserChoice)
{
    if (UserChoice == '+')
    {
        double reSultOutputAdd = vAdd1 + vAdd2;
        cout << "The result for addition: " << reSultOutputAdd << '\n';
    }
}

int main() {
    CalCulation();  
}
```

Comment: 'UserChoice' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: I forget the formal parameter list on ```ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, char UserChoice)``` but now it should work

Comment: There's a careless parameter switch in this answer which, of course, doesn't matter for commuting operators, but will matter for `-` and `/` for example. Otherwise I can't see why this wouldn't work,.

Comment: @Bathsheba I edited the question with more full version of code for more clarification to make it easier to debug

Comment: Your ```ReSults(double,double, char)``` function prototype, does not match its definition ```void ReSults(double vAdd1, double vAdd2, double vSub1, double vSub2, double vMul1, double vMul2, double vDiv1, double vDiv2, char UserChoice)``` That's why it never worked, also add ```break``` in switch cases

Comment: @Zach_Mose Ok, and not it is taking 2 doubles at a time?

Comment: Hopefully you'll be on the right track, also check what @Bathsheba said about ```-``` and ```/```

Comment: @Zach_Mose I see someone is devoting your answer without any reason, I have less votes to vote it up because it helps me)

Comment: Don't worry about it, I think we're all here to learn and help each other.

Comment: I'll remove my downvote once the parameters are fixed.

Comment: @Bathsheba On which line?

Comment: 'void ReSults(double vAdd2, double vAdd1, char UserChoice)'

Comment: @Bathsheba I don't understand what You are pointing, post an answer with enough documentation so I can learn from it

Comment: @SeePlusPlus-Kid: I've made the edit. Downvote converted to upvote.

Comment: @Bathsheba Cool

Comment: Thanks at @Bathsheba and SeePlusPlus-Kid

Answer (score 0):

Well you could make a bool and check if the bool is true like this

```
bool addition = false;

void CalCulation()
{
    cout << "Choice: "; char UserChoice; cin>>UserChoice;
    double vAdd1, vAdd2;
    switch(UserChoice)
    {
    case '+':
        cout << " + :: Enter the first value: "; cin << vAdd1;
        cout << " + :: Enter the second value: "; cin >> vAdd2;
    addition = true;
        ReSults(vAdd1, Vadd2)
    }
}
void ReSults(double, double)
{
    if(addition)
    {
        double reSultOutputAdd = vAdd1+vAdd2;
        cout << "The result for addition: "<< reSultOutputAdd << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: I know the Bool method but I want to pass it directly without using any bool